In php, will pg_field_type() result in an extra communication with the database?
If pg_field_type() makes a call to database in any way, it can be expensive. If not, it is "cheap" in the boundaries of being cheap in PHP.
So the question is, will calling pg_field_type() make any extra communication with the database, or is it all just getting metadata from the result that PHP already got from the database? Being yes or no, is it always the case and why?

Yes, there is an extra communication (per worker process) with the database when you first attempt to get type names.
PHP's pg module will query the entire pg_type table and cache the result.
So if you need a "cheap" method, use pg_field_type_oid and manually convert from oid to type name.

"and manually convert from oid to type name" -- In this case, do you mean I would manually fetch the "oid->type name" map once only after connection to the database, and then use it to manually convert the results of pg_field_type_oid()?

"PHP's pg module will query the entire pg_type table and cache the result." -- in simpler words, even if I issue 10 queries and pg_type() for each field in each result set, there will still be only one extra communication?

Yes, still only one extra communication, an exception is if you create new tables, because there will be new oids.

I meant you can create an array to map oid and type name, because I think usually the database won't change too much once it is set up.
